# Private association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have two ActiveRecord models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars,:dependent=>:destroy
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

My design dictates that `Bar` needs to be associated to `Foo`, but `Foo` is only associated to `Bar` for the database dependency - to make sure that when an instance of `Foo` is deleted, all associated instances of `Bar` will also be deleted. Aside from that, code that uses `Foo` should not know about `Bar`, and I don't want the association methods to be accessible from the `Foo` objects.

I've tried declaring `private` before the `has_many` declaration in `Foo`, but it doesn't work(I guess it only works for methods declared directly with `def`...).

Is there any way to make the association private, or to achieve the database dependency without creating a `Bar` association in `Foo`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must put the `private` declaration *after* you call `has_many`, as it is not till then that the methods for the association are defined:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, :dependent => :destroy
  private :bars, :bars=
end

Foo.first.bars
#=> #<NoMethodError: private method `registrations' called for #<Foo:0x007fc767adca88>>
```

Comment: Thanks! I also made `bar_ids` and `bar_ids=` private - not as important as making `bars` and `bars=` private, but it should be noted for the completeness of the solution.